# 404 error in yii. url not working

Tags: .htaccess, yii

My url

```
'urlManager'=>array(
                          'urlFormat'=>'path',
                          'showScriptName'=>false,
                          'rules'=>array(
                                            '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/view',
                                           '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
                                          '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
                                         ),
```

My htaccess

```
RewriteEngine  On
RewriteBase  /
RewriteCond   %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond   %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule    ^(.*)\?*$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: I want Like this but not working 
neerayii/site/contact

Comment: did you enable a2enmod?

Comment: i have check mod_rewrite . its already loaded.

Comment: but when change the <Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
</Directory>

Comment: @rohit 's answer is true.. did you try it?

Comment: Yes .. i was try it but not worked.

Comment: Actually http://localhost/neerayii/ is working when click on any menu then 404 error..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me. Please try this

```
'urlManager'=>array(
    'urlFormat'=>'path',
        'rules'=>array(
            '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/view',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
        ),
        'showScriptName'=>false,
    ),
```

In htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on

# if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php
```

Comment: thanks bro ... its worked... my mistake... htaccess is on wrong place.. :-)